# Can we rate limit kong oauth2 token endpoint call?

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, kong

We have enabled oauth2 plugin globally so all underlying services and routes and consumers get the oauth2 plugin. There are instances where too many access token requests come into Kong on /oauth2/token path and we are trying to see how we can use rate limit plugin to rate limit those calls? Any guidance is appreciated

Thanks

Havent found anything in Kong Docs suggesting on how to try this

Answer (score 0):

You can follow a double hop access pattern in combination with basic auth for the oauth request in Kong wherein the first hop will take care of the rate limiting and the second hop will to the actual token generation. The approach is described [here](https://medium.com/@yaduvesh/rate-limiting-kong-oauth2-token-generation-by-consumer-approach-101-34b365851666)